# Wrong index after monthly resampling of Dataframe, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame has the following format:

[image]

I resampled the values based on a monthly basis, but the problem is that even the datatime index start from 2017-07-08, the Date Column after grouping by month and finding the mean, start from 2017-01-31. (There are not data at all in my DataFrame from January 2017 to August 2017). The data recording has started from August 2017.

[image]

[image]

Could you please give me some insights to understand what is happening?

Comment: What is the output of `flowData4.index.min()`?

Comment: Timestamp('2017-01-09 00:00:00')

Comment: So that implies that you have data from January 2017...

Comment: The data in the DataFrame is sorted and it starts from August 2017

Comment: But you just saw that there is data from `Timestamp('2017-01-09 00:00:00')`, no?

Comment: Did you get the answer? I am having the same problem